# How to filter for specific checking accounts from a banking partner of Banno?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

For our solution, we require to filter transactions for only those transactions that come from a specific checking account. We're looking to find an attribute that we can filter for to make sure that that is the account we should receive the transactions from.

Could anyone point us in the right direction or tell us what the unique identifier could be that helps us filter for only those related (checking) accounts?

We tried looking in the transaction and account attributes to figure out the unique identifier that had to do with the specific checking account product, but did not find it.
We've tried accountType and AccountSubType, but these are not specific enough as it's a specific checking account we're looking for that has our product attached to it.

Now we're doing things manually but we'll need to automate this soon.

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer

You'll likely have the best success in filtering transactions for a 'specific financial product offering at the financial institution' by getting closer to the *core*.

For credit unions, that would mean using the [SymXchange API](https://jackhenry.dev/symxchange-api-docs/).

For banks, that would mean using the [Enterprise REST API (jXchange)](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/).

Both of those APIs offer deeper data elements than the ones offered in the Banno Digital Toolkit.

### The long answer

Your best bet is to use jXchange / SymXchange.

If you stick to using the Banno Digital Toolkit, there are some options that may work okayish in some circumstances but which likely wouldn't be a good fit for your use case.

You mentioned trying to use the `accountType` and `accountSubType` from the [Accounts API](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#account-types). That gets sort of close in that you could determine that a particular account is a `Deposit / Checking` pairing. However, you would not be able to determine that a particular checking account was a 'Super Duper Premium Checking' account instead of a 'No-Frills Basic Checking' account. I'm fairly certain that you came to the same conclusion, but wanted this as part of the answer for posterity.

It *may* be possible to use the `name` property from the Accounts API to make that kind of determination, but it wouldn't be *reliable*. The way that the `name` is built up within the core is configurable by each financial institution so you wouldn't necessarily be able to rely on seeing the same thing across different institutions. Also, the `name` of an account is user-modifiable so you wouldn't necessarily be able to rely on consistency as user may change their account name to be 'direct deposit', or 'funds for school', or anything else.